# Multi-threads program architecture C pthread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'd like to create multi-threads program in C (Linux) with:

1. Infinite loop with infinite number of tasks
2. One thread per one task
3. Limit the total number of threads, so if for instance total threads number is more then MAX_THREADS_NUMBER, do sleep(), until total threads number become less then MAX_THREADS_NUMBER, continue after.

**Resume:** I need to do infinite number of tasks(one task per one thread) and I'd like to know how to implement it using pthreads in C.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_THREADS 50


pthread_t thread[MAX_THREADS];
int counter;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    counter += 1;
    printf("Job %d started\n", counter);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int ret;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        ret = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (ret != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
    }

    // Wait all threads to finish
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

How to make this loop infinite?

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
    ret = pthread_create(&(thread[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
    if (ret != 0)
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
}
```

I need something like this:

```
while (1) {
    if (thread_number > MAX_THREADS_NUMBER)
        sleep(1);

    ret = pthread_create(...);
    if (ret != 0)
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
}
```

Comment: Use a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool).

Comment: What you want is not clear enough. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @shrike I need to do infinite number of tasks(one task per one thread) and I'd like to know how to implement it using pthreads in C. Is this what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

Your current program is based on a simple dispatch design: the initial thread creates worker threads, assigning each one a task to perform. Your question is, how you make this work for any number of tasks, any number of worker threads. The answer is, you don't: your chosen design makes such a modification basically impossible.

Even if I were to answer your stated questions, it would not make the program behave the way you'd like. It might work after a fashion, but it'd be like a bicycle with square wheels: not very practical, nor robust -- not even fun after you stop laughing at how silly it looks.

The solution, as I wrote in a comment to the original question, is to change the underlying design: from a simple dispatch to a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) approach.

Implementing a thread pool requires two things: First, is to change your viewpoint from starting a thread and having it perform a task, to each thread in the "pool" grabbing a task to perform, and returning to the "pool" after they have performed it. Understanding this is the hard part. The second part, implementing a way for each thread to grab a new task, is simple: this typically centers around a data structure, protected with locks of some sort. The exact data structure does depend on what the actual work to do is, however.

Let's assume you wanted to parallelize the calculation of the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) (or rather, the escape time, or the number of iterations needed before a point can be ruled to be outside the set; the Wikipedia page contains pseudocode for exactly this). This is one of the "embarrassingly parallel" problems; those where the sub-problems (here, each point) can be solved without any dependencies.

Here's how I'd do the core of the thread pool in this case. First, the escape time or iteration count needs to be recorded for each point. Let's say we use an `unsigned int` for this. We also need the number of points (it is a 2D array), a way to calculate the complex number that corresponds to each point, plus some way to know which points have either been computed, or are being computed. Plus mutually exclusive locking, so that only one thread will modify the data structure at once. So:

```
typedef struct {
    int               x_size, y_size;
    size_t            stride;
    double            r_0,  i_0;
    double            r_dx, i_dx;
    double            r_dy, i_dy;
    unsigned int     *iterations;
    sem_t             done;
    pthread_mutex_t   mutex;
    int               x, y;
} fractal_work;
```

When an instance of `fractal_work` is constructed, `x_size` and `y_size` are the number of columns and rows in the `iterations` map. The number of iterations (or escape time) for point `x`,`y` is stored in `iterations[x+y*stride]`. The real part of the complex coordinate for that point is `r_0 + x*r_dx + y*r_dy`, and imaginary part is `i_0 + x*i_dx + y*i_dy` (which allows you to scale and rotate the fractal freely).

When a thread grabs the next available point, it first locks the `mutex`, and copies the `x` and `y` values (for itself to work on). Then, it increases `x`. If `x >= x_size`, it resets `x` to zero, and increases `y`. Finally, it unlocks the `mutex`, and calculates the escape time for that point.

However, if `x == 0 && y >= y_size`, the thread posts on the `done` semaphore and exits, letting the initial thread know that the fractal is complete. (The initial thread just needs to call `sem_wait()` once for each thread it created.)

The thread worker function is then something like the following:

```
void *fractal_worker(void *data)
{
    fractal_work *const work = (fractal_work *)data;
    int           x, y;

    while (1) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(work->mutex));

        /* No more work to do? */
        if (work->x == 0 && work->y >= work->y_size) {
            sem_post(&(work->done));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(work->mutex));
            return NULL;
        }

        /* Grab this task (point), advance to next. */
        x = work->x;
        y = work->y;
        if (++(work->x) >= work->x_size) {
            work->x = 0;
            ++(work->y);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(work->mutex));

        /* z.r = work->r_0 + (double)x * work->r_dx + (double)y * work->r_dy;
           z.i = work->i_0 + (double)x * work->i_dx + (double)y * work->i_dy;

           TODO: implement the fractal iteration,
                 and count the iterations (say, n)

                 save the escape time (number of iterations)
                 in the work->iterations array; e.g.
            work->iterations[(size_t)x + work->stride*(size_t)y] = n;
        */
    }
}
```

The program first creates the `fractal_work` data structure for the worker threads to work on, initializes it, then creates *some number of threads* giving each thread the address of that `fractal_work` structure. It can then call `fractal_worker()` itself too, to "join the thread pool". (This pool automatically "drains", i.e. threads will return/exit, when all points in the fractal are done.)

Finally, the main thread calls `sem_wait()` on the `done` semaphore, as many times as it created worker threads, to ensure all the work is done.

The exact fields in the `fractal_work` structure above do not matter. However, it is at the very core of the thread pool. Typically, there is at least one mutex or rwlock protecting the work details, so that each worker thread gets unique work details, as well as some kind of flag or condition variable or semaphore to let the original thread know that the task is now complete.

In a multithreaded server, there is usually only one instance of the structure (or variables) describing the work queue. It may even contain things like minimum and maximum number of threads, allowing the worker threads to control their own number to dynamically respond to the amount of work available. This sounds magical, but is actually simple to implement: when a thread has completed its work, or is woken up in the pool with no work, and is holding the mutex, it first examines how many queued jobs there are, and what the current number of worker threads is. If there are more than the minimum number of threads, and no work to do, the thread reduces the number of threads, and exits. If there are less than the maximum number of threads, and there is a lot of work to do, the thread first creates a new thread, then grabs the next task to work on. (Yes, any thread can create new threads into the process. They are all on equal footing, too.)

A lot of the code in a practical multithreaded application using one or more thread pools to do work, is some sort of bookkeeping. Thread pool approaches very much concentrates on the data, and the computation needed to be performed on the data. I'm sure there are much better examples of thread pools out there somewhere; the hard part is to think of a good task for the application to perform, as the data structures are so task-dependent, and many computations are so simple that parallelizing them makes no sense (since creating new threads does have a small computational cost, it'd be silly to waste time creating threads when a single thread does the same work in the same or less time).

Many tasks that benefit from parallelization, on the other hand, require information to be shared between workers, and that requires a lot of thinking to implement correctly. (For example, although solutions exist for parallelizing molecular dynamics simulations efficiently, most simulators still calculate and exchange data in separate steps, rather than at the same time. It's just that hard to do right, you see.)

All this means that you cannot expect to be able to write the code, unless you understand the concept. Indeed, truly understanding the concepts are the hard part: writing the code is comparatively easy.

Even in the above example, there are certain tripping points: Does the order of posting the semaphore and releasing the mutex matter? (Well, it depends on what the thread that is waiting for the fractal to complete does -- and indeed, if it is waiting yet.) If it was a condition variable instead of a semaphore, it would be essential that the thread that is interested in the fractal completion is waiting on the condition variable, otherwise it would miss the signal/broadcast. (This is also why I used a semaphore.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you post the full example please.

Comment: @SebastianRockefeller: Why would you need the full example? As I said, the overall concept of a thread pool is the hard part, and what matters the most. Go look it up in your reference materials, the links at the Wikipedia page, or one of the web search hits when you search for `"c thread pool"`.